# How to autosave RichEditBox text?

Tags: uwp, autosave, fileloadexception, richeditbox

I tried `FileIO.WriteTextAsync();` with many events including Grid.Loaded and RichEditBox.TextChanged, but that method is asynchronous and conflicts with process called previous cycle. As a result, `System.IO.FileLoadException` with following description:

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

So what can I do in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TextChanged` event is fired too frequently - you can type several characters in a second - handling the `TextChanged` event is too heavy for the UI thread.

You can do this save operation in a Timer Tick event handler, set an Interval long enough to ensure the operation is completed before the next Tick occurs.

```
DispatcherTimer timer; 

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    timer = new DispatcherTimer() { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10) };
    timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
    timer.Start();
}

private async void Timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
    await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, tbInput.Text);
}
```